# Moving contents of canvas without clearing the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to implement pan functionality in my canvas and it is working. Essentially, I am

- getting the updated viewportTransform
- using that on the setTransform() method
- **clearing the entire canvas**
- redrawing the content

A rough code is:

```
canvasContext.setTransform(vp[0], vp[1], vp[2], vp[3], vp[4], vp[5]);
canvasContext.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
drawContent();
```

Is there a way I can avoid clearing the entire canvas? This makes the app slow.

Comment: Draw non-transparent view on top of old view. Or add single color rectangle on top before redraw

Comment: Actually my canvas is transparent over another element.

Comment: I would not agree that clearing the canvas is slow. clearRect is even used in 60fps games.

Comment: Not using alpha in canvas is much more important for productivity, and `clearRect()` is quick enough (just hold the width and height in variables - no need to resolve every frame with `window.innerWidth` etc)

Comment: Not re-rendering the whole canvas is generally not an option. Only very specific types of animations are conducive to it, but there's no enough details here to say how or whether you'd be able to make this adaptation. From the sound of "panning", it seems virtually impossible. It could be an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876) where you've presumed Y (not clearing canvas) is the solution to performance problem X, but without full context, you may well be missing clear-cut, easier to implement optimizations Z, S and T. Best to provide a [mcve] and plenty of context.